# Multiple attempts at setting up a USB printer on a router/network have not worked as expected

Tags: networking, router, printing, printer

All of this involves computers using Windows 10.

I recently switched to a new ISP that my town manages; the town is slowly installing fiber infrastructure and it is much more reliable than my old cable ISP.

I had my own modem and router from the cable ISP but when switching decided to just use the fiber equipment provided by the new ISP.

The old router was a Netgear Nighthawk R7000P. It still works with the usb printer on its own subnet. The new fiber router is a Nokia Gateway 3; it recognizes the printer in the router config pages, but my laptop doesn’t actually seem to be able to communicate with the printer.

On the cable setup, I had my USB only printer connected into my router’s USB port and available on the network without issue. More or less the setup outlined in this guide: https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-a-USB-Printer-to-a-Network

The fiber equipment doesn’t work with the same setup: Anytime I try to print a test page the print queue sits until it errors out.

I’ve tried several different port configurations on the printer, all unsuccessful. The ISP support said they haven’t seen anyone successfully set this up. I think it’s because the router has username/password enabled printer sharing and I can’t figure out how to set up the windows network printer to use a username/password:

Screenshot of router config page:

> [image: Screenshot.]

After giving up on this, I’ve tried using my old router as a sort of print server, since I know it works standalone. I’ve tried a few different network configurations but also can’t get this to work:

> [image: Setup attempts diagram.]

- When the second router is using the WAN port and its own subnet/IP address, a laptop connected directly to the second router can still print test pages, but I cannot get my work laptop on the primary router to print anything.
- When the second router is using the LAN port and DHCP is turned off, no device connected to either router will print anything.

I’m by no means a networking expert so may be misconfiguring something. If anyone has tips to try I’m all open to advice.

I suppose I could connect all devices to the secondary router and just use the primary as a bridge to the ISP, but I'd like to avoid that approach since the new ISP provided multiple routers in a mesh setup to have better Wifi coverage in the house.

Answer (score 0):

> I’ve tried several different port configurations on the printer, all
> unsuccessful. The ISP support said they haven’t seen anyone
> successfully set this up. I think it’s because the router has
> username/password enabled printer sharing and I can’t figure out how
> to set up the windows network printer to use a username/password:

**Sharing a printer from a computer:**

Sharing a USB connected Printer must be done from a PC (not router) and sharing it out that way.

This means leaving said PC on (not suspended or off) all the time.

(**A) Better is a USB Print Server.**

This will put your printer (most USB printers) on any network.

Here is an example of such a Print Server.  Do a bit of research for what you want, but a Print Server is the most reliable way to connect a USB Printer on the Network.

[USB Print Server Example](https://www.amazon.ca/IOGEAR-Server-1-Port-GPSU21-Silver/dp/B000FW60FW/ref=asc_df_B000FW60FW/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292901645034&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14512450941429413232&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1002350&hvtargid=pla-547533053887&psc=1)

**(B) A specific Router may include a USB Printer Server.**

However: (a) many routers do not; (b) it is still a Printer Server even within a router ; and (c) if you find such a router, your ISP needs to support it if you use it as your main router.

Comment: Thanks John - I'm trying to avoid buying a USB Print Server if possible; I'm viewing this partly as a learning exercise to see how this could be configured using my network components, either by properly configuring the primary fiber router or by properly setting up a secondary router that has a known working USB print server

Comment: You either need a Printer Server, or one built into a Router.  A router with a USB port (I have a couple) is not necessarily a Printer Server router.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with @John. A printserver may not work either.

The issue is that most USB-only printers are low-cost host-based printers (GDI or equivalent). These rely on the PC's graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the paper. One problem with this type of printer is that they are hard to network.

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Connect the printer to a PC and share it.
2. Connect the printer via a **compatible** printserver. Most reputable printserver manufacturers supply printer compatibility list for their devices. If your printer is not in the list, you must assume it will not work.

More expensive printers, those that support a printer language (PDL) like PCL5, PCL6, PostScript, ESC/P etc do not suffer from this and will work fine with any printserver or router/printserver. Note that some HP printers support something called PCL3. That is not a PDL, bears no relation to PCL5/6, and is host-based.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption your printer worked just fine connected to the nighthawk on the old network, I think you have a routing issue.   When you connect the nighthawk to the new router (new Lan Network), unless you change the nighthawk settings, it acts as a router and protects all its connected devices within its own Lan network.

There should be a setting in the Nighthawk to change if from a router to a pass through, which would make it act like a switch and add all its connected devices to the New network.  At which point the printer connected would also become available.

From the Netgear community:  Put it into AP mode. It will function as an Ethernet switch + WAP. If you don't need the WAP, then disable Wi-Fi. You can push the physical Wi-Fi button for about 2 seconds to turn them off.

Answer (score 0):

After far too much searching and trial and error the following worked for me:

- Add printer or scanner
- The printer that I want isn't listed
- Select a shared printer by name
- http://"ROUTER IP":631/printers/"DEVICE NAME"

  - E.g. http://192.168.1.254:631/printers/Brother_HL-L2320D_series_255
- Select and install the appropriate driver
- Click on "Print server properties" in the right hand pane in Printers & scanners in Windows Settings
- Ports
- Change Port Settings (Administrator Button)
- Select your port (should be at the end of the list)
- Configure Port...
- Select "Use the specified user account"
- Fill in the Username and Password you set for Printer Sharing on your router
- Select "Use same security setting for all users"